# pycurl post request hangs infinitely on perform()

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pycurl

I am trying to make a post request using pycurl but request hangs infinitely on `c.perform()`. My code is:

```
    try:
        from io import BytesIO
    except ImportError:
        from io import StringIO as BytesIO

    buffer = BytesIO()
    self.c.setopt(self.c.URL, 'http://pycurl.io/')
    self.c.setopt(self.c.HEADER, 0)
    self.c.setopt(self.c.POST, 1)
    self.c.perform()
    self.c.close()
    body = buffer.getvalue()

    status = self.c.getinfo(self.c.HTTP_CODE)
    response_data = {
        'is_fed_successfully': True
    }'
```

And just to be clear, there's no error. The request just hangs infinitely without any response.

Comment: where is `pycurl.Curl()`?

Comment: `self.c = pycurl.Curl()` That's in a method of the class

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem too. What worked for me was to pass some empty data using POSTFIELDS. You could try adding this line.

```
self.c.setopt(self.c.POSTFIELDS,'')
```

I'm guessing it is hanging because it is waiting for data that never comes.